# DotNetOpenAuth - how to uniquely identify Google users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I am using DotNetOpenAuth to identify Google users. I am currently retrieving their e-mail address and saving a copy of that in my database. However, what if they change their e-mail address in their Google account? Then my copy can no longer be linked to their profile.

Is there a way to uniquely identify a Google account through DotNetOpenAuth?

Comment: Are you talking about a user completely changing their Google username? I don't think you can do that and still be considered the same Google user. See [here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8158).

Comment: It is true that their account e-mail can't change. But what if I get the contact e-mail? And what if I (for instance) authenticate with Flickr instead, where e-mail change is possible?

Comment: Oh OK. You should probably be storing the **ClaimedIdentifier** then. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196965/storing-dotnetopenauth-information-and-user-info-retrieval)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use the `IAuthenticationResponse.ClaimedIdentifier` to uniquely identify users!

[OpenID's security model is based on this design](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#identifying).  Using email addresses is *insecure* in many ways.  Any Provider can issue a positive assertion claiming that the user owns a particular email address.  OpenID doesn't prevent the OP from lying about email addresses, so if you just used email addresses and the user key then you'd be wide open to user spoofing attacks.  Even if the OP isn't trying to be dishonest, you couldn't generally trust it because you don't know whether the OP verified the email address or simply asked the user what their email address was.

Even if you trust Google to not lie, there are several reasons (some of them can be mitigated, but aren't obvious) to not treat email address as the user identifier.  For example, Google lets users change the email address behind their Google account.  If the user did this and then returned to your web site, your site would identify them as a different user.  Even worse, if another user later claimed a recycled email address for their new Google account, your site would recognize them as the older user and give the new user access to a bunch of old user data.

OpenID Claimed Identifiers are designed to avoid all this trouble.

Comment: It would be useful if you could expand on the reasons or provide reference to more information.

Comment: I've added some reasons and a link to the relevant part of the OpenID 2.0 spec as requested.